# ¿Usar BLADE sin Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy aprendiendo PHP y me gustaría poder usar BLADE. Hay alguna forma de usarlo sin tener que usar Laravel?.

He encontrado algo de información en ingles, pero no se como comenzar a usarlo.
Este es el que he encontrado por ejemplo:
https://github.com/ventoviro/windwalker-edge

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Qué es lo que no te resulta? Estás usando composer en tu aplicación?

Comment: @amenadiel abajo explico lo que me preguntas. Gracias por responder

Comment: Ok, copia lo que te puso @Chivito, pero añade antes `require_once   '/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: Te dejé un demo en https://github.com/amenadiel/windwalker_demo clónalo y sígue las instrucciones del README.md

Comment: Gracias @Amenadiel!! Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

podes usar otros motores de plantillas, tenes PlatesPHP, Twig, entre otros, mi preferido es Twig que es del frameworl Symfony, es muy potente y tiene muchas caracteristicas pero si lo que quieres es usar ese que descreibis, tenes que tener instalado Composer.

Una vez que hayas instalado Composer, debes dirigirte a la carpeta de tu proyecto y agregar Windwalker Edge a u proyecto.

Para agregar el motor de plantillas a tu proyecto debes agregar en el composer.json y si no lo tienes, debes crearlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de eso ya estarias listo para poder usarlo, solo debes dirigirte al archivo desde donde quieres renderizar y ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el ejemplo de recién solo renderizas html, no estas mostrando ninguna vista porque no definiste una ruta en donde están estas vistas

Para definir esas rutas lo que tenes que hacer es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por defecto siempre te va a tomar la primera ruta

Si lees detenidamente todo esta en la URL que pasaste, te dice como hacer las cosas paso a paso.

Avísame si te funciono, saludos.

Comment: Chiiviito gracias por responder. Creo que mis problemas son varios. Primero me di cuenta que no sabía utilizar composer, por lo cual miré un tutorial y logre al menos subir un nivel hasta que caí en un nuevo problema. He probado Twig, BladeOne, philo/laravel-blade (Todos motores de plantillas de PHP) y en todos tengo el problema de que no se como ejecutarlos. Leo la documentación, ingreso todo y luego en el XAMPP me termina arrojando errores que no encuentra la ruta u otras cosas, y las rutas a mi parecer las indico bien. Terminé desinstalando todo y creo que seguiré aprendiendo PHP sin nada.

Comment: Creo que estas teniendo problemas con POO, te recomiendo  aprender PHP POO, porque quizás no entiendes la logia y por eso no podes ejecutar ningún motor de plantillas.

La logica y funcionamiento son casi exactamente iguales en todos los motores de plantillas, me extraña que no puedas ejecutar ni uno.

Comment: nuevamente gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder. Voy a tener muy en cuenta lo que me decís, quizás sea eso. Voy a hacerte caso y voy a buscar algún videotutorial. Con respecto a mi publicación, ahora probé por última vez con el windwalker-edge que comentaba en la pregunta y lo mismo, llegué al HOLA MUNDO, pero al modificar los path por las carpetas por las mías así: $paths = array(
 __DIR__ . 'views',
 'layouts',
 'cache',
);

y al poner un index.blade.php en views, me arroja el error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'EdgeFileLoader' not found in stack trace: #0 {main}

Comment: @Chiiviito ahí falta algo. Si no haces un `require_once './vendor/autoload.php';` como primerísima fila después del opening tag `<?PHP` el script no va a saber qué significa `use Windwalker\...` porque el autoload es el que mapea un FQCN a un archivo específico.

Comment: @amenadiel es verdad, me re olvide de incluir el composer en el documento, no me habia dado cuenta